# how to change my android app font

Tags: android, fonts

all

I have use follow code to change font, but do not support FragmentActivity in some android devices.
Who can help me ,than

```
public final class FontsOverride {

    public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
            String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
        final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                fontAssetName);
        replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
    }

    protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
            final Typeface newTypeface) {
        try {
            final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                    .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
            staticField.setAccessible(true);
            staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You then need to overload the few default fonts, for example:

```
FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", "MyFontAsset.ttf");
FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", "MyFontAsset2.ttf");
FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SANS_SERIF", "MyFontAsset3.ttf");
```

Or course if you are using the same font file, you can improve on this to load it just once.

However I tend to just override one, say "MONOSPACE", then set up a style to force that font typeface application wide:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/monospaceTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/monospaceButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="monospaceTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>

<style name="monospaceButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```

Note: This will work for API version > 16 only..

Answer (score 0):

I have get anther solution, please see below source code

1. copy your font files to assets folder.
     assets
       --fonts
         --FuturaLT.ttf
         --XXXX.ttf
         --FuturaLT.ttf
2. add source code in your appliction class

public class MyApp extends Application {

```
public MyApp() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

    // change App Font
    changeAppFont();

} 


private void changeAppFont(){

    setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", "fonts/FuturaLT.ttf");
    setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT_BOLD", "fonts/FuturaLT-Bold.ttf");

    setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", "fonts/FuturaLT-Oblique.ttf");
    setDefaultFont(this, "SANS_SERIF", "fonts/FuturaLT.ttf");
    setDefaultFont(this, "SERIF", "fonts/FuturaLT.ttf");
}

public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
        String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
    final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            fontAssetName);
    replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
}

protected static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
        final Typeface newTypeface) {
    try {
        final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
        staticField.setAccessible(true);
        staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}